# Scrapy, How to Create Different Headings for Each Pages?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy, so please be kind:))

So, I'm going to scrape some JSON files from devtools-Network from multiple pages with scrapy. However each of the pages have different headers. How can I solve this

Lets use this

```
    import scrapy
    import json


        import scrapy
    import json


    class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'quote'
        allowed_domains = ['shopee.co.id']
        page = 1
        start_urls = ['https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword=deodorant&limit=50&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        for quote in data["quotes"]:
            yield {"quote": quote["text"]}
        if data["has_next"]:
            self.page += 1

            url = "https://shopee.co.id/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword=deodorant&limit=50&newest="+str(self.page)+"&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2"

            headers = {
            'accept'          : '*/*'
            ,'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
            ,'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
            ,'if-none-match-' : '55b03-ba4b020f9bad34856fc4771b0aaedc93'
            ,'referer'        : 'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=deodorant&page='+str(self.page)
            ,'sec-fetch-dest' : 'empty'
            ,'sec-fetch-mode' : 'cors'
            ,'sec-fetch-site' : 'same-origin'
            ,'user-agent'     : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36'
            ,'x-api-source'   : 'pc'
            ,'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, method='GET', headers=headers)
```

How would I add a unique headers for each pages, for example,

```
header = {
     'referer': 'some_reference_pagenumber',
     }
```

I tried the script and tried to tinker with it, yet it always result in
`referer:none` in the shell, thus unable to scrape

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you check offician documentation for `Requests` ? Maybe it can get `header`  as option. But I would expect it use `referer`  automatically. Frankly, in most situations I don't care of `referer` - mostly servers doesn't care if you have `referer`

Comment: The website I'm currently aiming to scrap requrires unique numbered referer sadly. I'm good if its a single header, we can just use header value in the request. But I'm confused if it changes per page

Comment: you can check Middlewares: [RefererMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer) - maybe it can help or you could use its source code to write own middleware.

Comment: BTW: you should add real URL for page which makes problem - this way we could see this problem

Comment: Okay I edited with the full script, thanks for the reminder

Comment: is this your real script ? Server doesn't sends `data["quotes"]` and `data["has_next"]` in JSON data but `data['items']` and `data['items'][0]['name']`, `data['items'][0]['price']`, etc. And I can read all data without headers. `yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)`.

Comment: BTW: whey I run it then only first request has `referer: none` (and it is natural) but other requests have correct referers - but I don't uses `headers`.

Comment: BTW: If I set wrong `referer` in `headers` and use it in `Request` then I see my wrong rereferee in console (so `Request` used it) but still it gives me all data.

Comment: BTW: don't you get error message ? Maybe all your problem is `data["quotes"]` which doesn't exists in JSON data and it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to add the parameters in headers that you want to change as per page. suppose you want to change `'referer'` according to some logic then initialize the headers without `'referer'`.

```
headers = {
            'accept'          : '*/*'
            ,'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
            ,'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
            ,'if-none-match-' : '55b03-ba4b020f9bad34856fc4771b0aaedc93'
            ,'sec-fetch-dest' : 'empty'
            ,'sec-fetch-mode' : 'cors'
            ,'sec-fetch-site' : 'same-origin'
            ,'user-agent'     : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36'
            ,'x-api-source'   : 'pc'
            ,'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
```

and as you know that headers is a dictionary and we can append it as we want. so now we can append it according to our logic. see below:

```
if 'deoderand' in keyword:
    headers['referer'] = f'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword={keyword}'

yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, method='GET', headers=headers)
```

every time, when your logic will be true it will modify your headers's `referer` as you want.